# How to only return the date part from datetime.datetime type?

Tags: python, datetime

```
date= dateutil.parser.parse('20150327T034556Z')
```

returns:

```
2015-03-27 03:45:56+00:00
```

How to get the date part without the time part: (2015-03-27)

Answer (score 5):

There is a date method for datetime objects.

```
>>> date = dateutil.parser.parse('20150327T034556Z')
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 27, 3, 45, 56, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> date.date()
datetime.date(2015, 3, 27)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html.

Comment: `date` is a method; it needs to be called.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
date.isoformat()
```

or

```
date.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
```

And you can choose how to it can look further.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat

Answer (score 3):

```
date = dateutil.parser.parse('20150327T034556Z').date()
```